# Comparing Dates in JavaScript For any Give Date Format

Tags: javascript, date-format, date-comparison

Suppose I have different formats of Dates like "MM/DD/YY", "DD/MM/YY", "YY/MM/DD", I want to compare dates based on any of the above given formats, in JavaScript. Something Like:

```
let date1 = "21/04/2021";
let date2 = "25/01/2021";
let format = "DD/MM/YY";
Date(date1, format) > Date(date2, format);
True
Date(date1, format) < Date(date2, format);
False
Date(date1, format) === Date(date2, format);
False
```

Also both dates will have **same format** while comparing. Is there a better way to do it other then using split('/')?

Comment: You can use a library like date-fns to parse custom formatted date strings: https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/parse

Comment: Don't think so. At some point the M, D, & Y each have to be separated so a valid date Object can be constructed from them (quite simple really). This, of course, would require one to `.split('/')` the string to accomplish that.

Comment: @Mogzon the think I am lookin for is still not achievable through**date-fns** since You have to define date like `new Date(2014, 1, 11)` and then give format, but in my case I dont want to parse date. I just want to provide date as a string 2014/01/11 and then format.

Comment: Also the purpose is not a Date transformation but a result of date comparison in terms of **-1, 0, 1**. Hope that makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions I found best way to compare dates for any given format using **moment library**.

`let result = moment(date1, format).isBefore(moment(date2, format))? -1: 1;`

1. result = -1 means date1 is smaller
2. result = 1 means date1 is greater or equal